Python Holoviz Interactive Graphics Lagging in Google Colab but Working Fine in VSCode
I'm using the Holoviz ecosystem (specifically HoloViews, Panel, and other related libraries) to display interactive graphics with zoom functionality that increases the granularity of the data. The code runs fine in VSCode, but when I run it in Google Colab, the performance slows down significantly, and I receive warnings. The interactive behavior (sometimes) works but with noticeable delays.
What steps can I take to optimize the performance and avoid the warnings in Colab?
!pip install hvplot panel param bokeh jupyter_bokeh -U
from google.colab import output
output.enable_custom_widget_manager()


import holoviews as hv
import panel as pn
from holoviews.streams import RangeXY
import numpy as np

hv.extension("bokeh")

from numba import jit
@jit
def mandel(x, y, max_iters):
    """
    Given the real and imaginary parts of a complex number,
    determine if it is a candidate for membership in the Mandelbrot
    set given a fixed number of iterations.
    """
    i = 0
    c = complex(x,y)
    z = 0.0j
    for i in range(max_iters):
        z = z*z + c
        if (z.real*z.real + z.imag*z.imag) >= 4:
            return i

    return 255

@jit
def create_fractal(min_x, max_x, min_y, max_y, image, iters):
    height = image.shape[0]
    width = image.shape[1]

    pixel_size_x = (max_x - min_x) / width
    pixel_size_y = (max_y - min_y) / height
    for x in range(width):
        real = min_x + x * pixel_size_x
        for y in range(height):
            imag = min_y + y * pixel_size_y
            color = mandel(real, imag, iters)
            image[y, x] = color

    return image

def get_fractal(x_range, y_range):
    (x0, x1), (y0, y1) = x_range, y_range
    image = np.zeros((600, 600), dtype=np.uint8)
    return hv.Image(create_fractal(x0, x1, -y1, -y0, image, 200),
                    bounds=(x0, y0, x1, y1))
    
range_stream = RangeXY(x_range=(-1., 1.), y_range=(-1., 1.))

dmap = hv.DynamicMap(get_fractal,streams=[range_stream])
dmap_panel = pn.panel(dmap)
dmap_panel

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1YGgZAA-E3YBqYMu2SSTdS1QcQXxlxf31?usp=sharing

